# How do I get 4K output resolution with GTX760 on Ubuntu Desktop 13.10?

Tags: nvidia, resolution

I have a Nvidia GTX760 with drivers installed. How do I get the option to go up to the 4K output resolution? I am only getting 1920x1080 and below options and I have a 39" Seiki 4K display.

Currently, following this thread to find answers: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164924